# How can I add non-CRUD actions to the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to create a simple CRUD interface for my Django app. The Django admin does 90% of what I need, but I have a couple of things that don't fit well.

Say I have a File model and a Validator model. Besides CRUDing them, I also need to be able to send a File to a Validator for validation. This is not a database action. Sending a file to a validator involves scheduling the file on the validators queue. Later (minutes or hours), when the validator completes, that fact will be noted in the database.

From a UX view, this naturally belongs on the File admin page as a dropdown to select a validator and a button. Is there a way to naturally add this to the admin?

(I am a django newbie, I apologize if this is a stupid question.)

Comment: You could use an admin action with an intermediary page: http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question. The admin allows you to extend it in almost any way you wish. I would personally start by looking at how to create [packages (apps) in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

You can extend the admin in many ways, [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/), other apps, custom dashboard to overwriting templates etc just to name a few.

There are also a lot of packages that already achieve [this](https://github.com/kaleidos/django-validated-file) too.

For task processing of the file look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue system.

More reading: [Customizing Django Admin Interface functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758509/customizing-django-admin-interface-functionality)

Comment: The link about admin actions is exactly what I didn't know to look for. Thanks. I knew about celery. The validation provided by that validated-file package is not what I need or want.