# Django admin customization for huge eshop administration

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm facing to big project. It's gonna be eshop administration and I dont have much experiences with Django admin. I've realized only CRUDs.

My question is if is there a way and how much is that way painful to implement some advanced stuff in django admin - basically the stuff that u have to write by yourself like complicated product adminsitration incuding variants is.

In the other hand the administration will include common CRUDs and flat pages, so it would be cool if there is a way how to use django admin CRUDs and Flatpages app.

Would you guys go for django admin or in this case you would write the admin in your own way?

Thank you guys.

EDIT:

Update from customer: The project is gonna be just eshop admin. The frontends (eshops) arr gonna by implemented individually.

Comment: Django admin is pretty advanced itself. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155624/is-django-admin-difficult-to-customize

Comment: Thank you. I think that those customizations like forum admin in just simple CRUD. It's not so advanced like eshop administrations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have to provide us more details on the project's specifications in order to answer your question.

What you should do is:

- Outline all specifications and requirements for the project
- Find if out if there are third party apps that meets some of those requirements

When you have those two things you can make a decision whether it's worth using Django Admin for your project.